# How to pass a selection argument in "query" method

Tags: java, android, sql, android-contentresolver

I am trying to get all albums that are by a particular artist by using the query method.
However, i am a beginner and i don't know how to pass a selection argument in the query method.

This is what i have so far:

```
artistAlbumCursor = getContentResolver().query(
                MediaStore.Audio.Artists.Albums.ALBUM, null,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST=?, new String[] {artistChosen},
                MediaStore.Audio.Artists.Albums.ALBUM + " ASC");
```

Where artistChosen is the String containing the artist needed.

As I said i don't actually know how to pass a selection argument in so this was just an attempt.

So i guess what I'm asking is, how do i pass a selection argument into the query method.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Looks correct. Did you try it?

Comment: Eclipse wouldn't let me because "the method query(...) is not applicable for the arguments (...)"

Comment: Please post the complete error message. It looks like one of the parameters isn't of the right type, intuitively I'd say it's the last one because you are sorting on the ALBUM where you should be sorting on one column in particular.

Comment: Thanks you were so close. It was the first one. It should have been MediaStore.Audio.Albums.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with this

```
artistAlbumCursor = getContentResolver().query(
                MediaStore.Audio.Artists.Albums.ALBUM, null,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST+ "=?", new String[] {artistChosen},
                MediaStore.Audio.Artists.Albums.ALBUM + " ASC");
```

Comment: Dont worry about the last comment. It was a rookie erroir by me. The uri should have been MediaStore.Audio.Albums.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI. Your answer was correct.